# fstab keeps asking for password, while trying to mount shared cifs

Tags: linux, command-line, fstab, cifs, shared-folders

I have the following entry in my fstab file:

```
//10.30.1.235/Restrito/BackupVms /backups/servidor01 cifs
vers=2.0,credentials=/spassword,iocharset=utf8,gid=0,uid=0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=$ 0 0
```

`spassword` is a credential file in `/` *(permission 644)* where I have my password and username.

Example:

```
username=admin
password=123456
```

If I execute in command line:

```
mount -t cifs //10.30.1.235/Restrito/BackupVms /backups/servidor01 cifs
vers=2.0,credentials=/spassword,iocharset=utf8,gid=0,uid=0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=$0 0
```

It works!

If, I try mount -a (cause it execute from fstab), the system asks me for the password.

I want it to mount automatically. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `/spassword` file needs a third line specifying the domain of the username. If `admin` is a local account on `10.30.1.235`, then the domain is simply the SMB name of the host `10.30.1.235`. But the domain cannot be omitted.

For example, if `10.30.1.235` is called `SERVIDOR01` (i.e. its CIFS share might be called `\\SERVIDOR01\Restrito` on a Windows workstation), and `admin` is a local account on it (i.e it might be more fully shown as `SERVIDOR01\admin`), then your `/spassword` file should contain:

```
username=admin
password=123456
domain=servidor01
```

Comment: Hi @telcoM! I just added domain=freenas.local but it didn't work.

Comment: possibly helpful: you can leave the password line out and it will prompt you for one. also you can use the `mount` command to view currently mounted drives and `umount` to drop already mapped drives (e.g., you need to re-mount same drive with different settings).